# Как открыть поля по выбору определенного пункта селекта?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, select

Есть селект и скрытые поля, которые должны отображаться при выборе 2 пункта меню селекта.

Что я делаю не верно?

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  if ($this.find("option").attr(value) === 2) {
    $('#hidden_fields').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#hidden_fields {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value='1' selected="selected">1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<div id='hidden_fields'>
  <p>Name:
    <input>
  </p>
  <p>Sex:
    <input>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что вы не правильно используете jquery =)

1. должно быть `$(this)`
2. если вы ищите через `find` в селекте, то тогда надо писать `$(this).find('option:selected')`
3. у вас идет сравнение не только по значению но еще и по типу `===`, то есть вы получаете строковое значение, а проверяете на значение `2` и типа `integer`

Есть много способов все сделать так как нужно. На выбор:

самый короткий

```
if ($(this).val() == 2)
```

или в вашем стиле

```
if ($("option:selected", this).attr('value') == 2)
```

или

```
if ( $(this).find('option:selected').text() == 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Не `$this`, а `$(this)`
2. Вам же не просто нужно найти какой-то `option`, а именно `selected`, а значит не `$this.find("option")`, а `$(this).find("option:selected")`.
3. value в `.attr()` нужно передавать строкой, т.е. не `.attr(value)`, а `.attr('value')`
4. Из `.attr('value')` вернётся строка, а значит `=== 2` не прокатит. Или используйте `parseInt()`, или, что ещё проще `== 2`.

Вся проблема была в условии `if`.

```
$("select").change(function() {
  if ($(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') == 2) {
    $('#hidden_fields').show();
  }
});
```

Это работает:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  if ($(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') == 2) {
    $('#hidden_fields').show();
  }
});
```