# Вопрос по javascript. Нужно чтобы при выборе пункта селектора "Другое" появлялось еще одно поле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Никак не могу понять как сделать вроде бы простую вещь. Прочитал много в интернете, но все никак не могу "уговорить" элемент работать как нужно.

Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="inputState" class="form-label px-4">Должность</label>
  <select name="inputState" id="inputState" class="form-select px-4">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Должность 1">Должность 1</option>
    <option value="Должность 2">Должность 2</option>
    <option value="Должность 3">Должность 3</option>
    <option value="Должность 4">Должность 4</option>
    <option value="Должность 5">Должность 5</option>
    <option value="Другое">Другое</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="hand_input" class="form-label">Введите вашу должность</label>
  <input name="hand_input" type="text" class="form-control" id="hand_input" placeholder="Должность">
</div>
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы изначально поле ручного вводы было скрыто, и только если пользователь выбрал в селекторе вариант "Другое", оно появилось и можно было ввести значение вручную.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Вот тут нашел очень похожий вопрос: [Как открыть поля по выбору определенного пункта селекта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456908/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0)
У себя пробую, но никак не получается "уговорить" все это работать.
Я вставлял код js за закрывающим тэгом  а код стилей вставлял и в код самого запускаемого файла html и в файл со стилями. Все равно не работает. Кажется там решение есть, я просто не понимаю куда что вставлять, чтобы все заработало...
Сейчас вставил код из той ссылки вот так:

[image: Изображение кода]

В итоге скрывать он поля скрывает, а отображать - не отображает.
Помогите плз.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const select = document.querySelector("#inputState");
    const wrapperForAppend = document.querySelector(".wrapper-for-append");

//можно также вместо строки создать любой элемент из js
    const nodeAsStringForAppend = `<div class="alternativePosition col-md-6">
  <label for="hand_input" class="form-label">Введите вашу должность</label>
  <input name="hand_input" type="text" class="form-control" id="hand_input" placeholder="Должность">
</div>`;

//при изменении срабатывает 'слушатель change', ну а дальше уже смотря какое значение в 'value' делаем то или иное
    select.addEventListener("change", ({ target: { value } }) => {
      const alternatePositionInDom = document.querySelector('.alternativePosition')
      if(value === "Другое" && !alternatePositionInDom) {
        //кроме insertAdjacentHTML есть и другие варианты
        wrapperForAppend.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', nodeAsStringForAppend)
      } else if(alternatePositionInDom) {
        alternatePositionInDom.remove()
      }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper-for-append col-md-6">
      <label for="inputState" class="form-label px-4">Должность</label>
      <select name="inputState" id="inputState" class="form-select px-4">
        <option></option>
        <option value="Должность 1">Должность 1</option>
        <option value="Должность 2">Должность 2</option>
        <option value="Должность 3">Должность 3</option>
        <option value="Должность 4">Должность 4</option>
        <option value="Должность 5">Должность 5</option>
        <option value="Другое">Другое</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```